# CellTable with Image Column

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-celltable

I have celltable with 4 column (name size addedBy modifiedBy )

all the value is filled during the run time.

The table actully show the documents.

Documents can be pdf, txt , doc so

1. i want to add icon before the name of the document.
2. and i also want one more Image column before name column

My code so far.

```
*
private CellTable<FDocument> getDocumentTable() {
        if (documentTable == null) {
            documentTable = new CellTable<FDocument>();
            documentTable.setSize("600px", "300px");
            documentTable.addColumn(nameColumnD, "NAME");
            documentTable.addColumn(sizeColumnD, "SIZE");
            documentTable.addColumn(modified_by_ColumnD, "MODIFIED BY");
            documentTable.addColumn(dateColumnD, "MODIFIED ON");


        }
        return documentTable;
    }


TextColumn<FDocument> idColumnD = new TextColumn<FDocument>() {             
            @Override
            public String getValue(FDocumentobject) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return object.getId();
            }
        };
        TextColumn<FDocument> nameColumnD = new TextColumn<FDocument>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(FDocumentobject) {
                return object.getName();
            }
        };          
        TextColumn<FDocument> sizeColumnD = new TextColumn<FDocument>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(FDocumentobject) {
                return object.getSize();                            
            }
        };
        TextColumn<FDocument> modified_by_ColumnD = new TextColumn<FDocument>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(FilenetDocument object) {
                return object.getModifiedBy();
            }
        };
        TextColumn<FDocument> dateColumnD = new TextColumn<FDocument>(){
            @Override
            public String getValue(FDocumentobject){
                return object.getModifiedOn();
            } 
        };

 private void addValuesToTable(){
        List<FDocument> FDC = null;


        /*
         * Adding data to folder Table
         */
        ArrayList<FDocument> documentsArrayList = new ArrayList<FDocument>();
        Iterator<String> iteratorDocument = documents.getDocuments().getDocumentCollection().keySet().iterator();
        while(iteratorDocument.hasNext()){
            String key = iteratorDocument.next().toString();
            FDocument value = documents.getDocuments().getDocumentCollection().get(key);
            documentsArrayList.add(new FDocument(value.getName(), value.getSize(),value.getModifiedBy(), value.getModifiedOn(),value.getId()));

        }
        FDC = documentsArrayList;

    // Create a data provider.

        ListDataProvider<FDocument> dataProvider1 = new ListDataProvider<FDocument>();

    // Connect the table to the data provider.

        dataProvider1.addDataDisplay(documentTable);

    // Add the data to the data provider, which automatically pushes it to the widget.

        List<FDocument> listDocument = dataProvider1.getList();
            for (FDocument fDocument: FDC) {

                listDocument.add(fDocument1);
            }
```

This the way i have made my table and the value.

Plz any one tell me the procedure

1. to add icon before the name of the document.
2. and i also want one more Image column before name column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *DefaultTableCellRenderer* to set custom renderer against the column with the desired icon. As shown below, the renderer creates a new label to mask all the cells within the selected column.

```
private class CellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{

 public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
 {
    JLabel label = new JLabel((String)value);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    Icon icon = new ImageIcon("icon.png");
    label.setIcon(icon);
    return label;
 }
}
```

And then apply it to your table as shown below:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new CellRenderer());
```

**Edited:**
If you're using GWT then see [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/FormatCellValuesSampleSmartGWT.htm) for an example code for Grid Cell format.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i am using GWT.

Answer (score 1):

For creating image column, You need to define a custom renderer that sets the icon on the label

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

  /*
   * @see TableCellRenderer#getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable, Object, boolean, boolean, int, int)
   */
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                 boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, 
                                                 int row, int column) {
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/moon.gif"));
    setText((String)value);
    setIcon(icon);
    return this;
  }
}
```

And then, use the renderer in a table as follows,

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class Sample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Sample");
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0,0,0));
    TableModel model = new AbstractTableModel() {
      public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return rowIndex + "," + columnIndex;
      }
      public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
      }
      public int getRowCount() {
        return 10;
      }
    };

    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new MyRenderer());
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    f.getContentPane().add(pane);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i am using GWT.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these will probably need a custom `TableCellRenderer`...

Refer to the API docs here... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html

You basically want to overwrite the `getTableCellRendererComponent()` method, and add in any additional code for rendering the image.

For example, to add an icon before the document, you would do the following...

```
public void MyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public MyTableCellRenderer(){
        super();
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){
        Component renderer = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,value,isSelected,hasFocus,row,column);
        if (row == 0 && renderer instanceof JLabel){ // where row == 0 is the row you want to add the icon to
            ((JLabel)renderer).setIcon(new ImageIcon("image.png"));
        }

        return renderer;
    }
}
```

You would need to set this as the `TableCellRenderer` for the column or table.

You would also do a similar thing for adding an image column to the table.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i am using GWT.